# Spring 5.3.9 - AbstractPDF controller

Tags: spring

I am upgrading the very old Spring framework to 5.3.9. All my controllers are working with annotations. Having issue (Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404) when calling exiting PDF generator controller. Below is the flow of the call. Could someone help me what am I missing ? Thank you!

//From the controller

```
If(action = "PRINT")
  return new ModelAndView("individualApplication.pdf.html","model",model);
}
```

//PDF controller

```
public class IndividualApplicationPdfPublicController extends AbstractPdfView {
  public void buildPdfDocument(Map model, Document document,
                PdfWriter pdfWriter, HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {}
            
}
```

//Configuration

```xml
<beans:bean id="individualApplication.pdf.html" class="controller.pdf.IndividualApplicationPdfPublicController">
</beans:bean>
    
<beans:bean id="publicUrlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">    
  <beans:property name="mappings">
    <beans:props>         
      <beans:prop key="/public/individualApplication.pdf.html">individualApplication.pdf.html</beans:prop>     
      </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: And with that you expect us to know what is wrong? Why does your "controller" extend a view class? Or is it a view rather then a controller? Which is probably the problem as your mapping to a View instead of a Controller.

Comment: I have answered my question. Please take a look.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the issue.

1. Updated the PDF controller removing the AbstarctPdfView extension.

[image]

pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);

2. Updated the controller to get the byteArray to flush to the browser.[image]

Return to the same page to stay on the same page.

Comment: Don't post code as images, and this is still wrong you should be returning the view which will render the PDF.

Comment: As I could not get much help on this old code, I just figured it myself and made it work. I could be still wrong or there may be a best way to do, but for now , it is working.

Comment: I have another issue wit hSecurityIntercepter. Can you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73239397/spring-security-interceptor